# Using execute()/executemany() for SQL statements in python

Tags: python, mysql, sql, mysql-python

I am using the MySQLdb module in python to write SQL statements. I am having a difficult time using variables in the way I'd like to. Here's my work:

```
stmt = '''
INSERT INTO Table1
(name, status)
SELECT (:name1, :status1)
        FROM dual
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM Table1
        WHERE name =(:name1))
'''
dic = {"name1":"Bob", "status1":"Active"}

dbcursor.executemany(stmt, dic) 
dbconnection.commit()
print("Insertion to Table1 committed\n\n")
```

This does not work, I eventually rollback with the error message `not all arguments converted during string formatting`. If I hardcode the dictionary values in then the insertion works fine. Can you point me to the proper way of using variables in place of hardcoded values?

Comment: Tip: use `"""..."""` triple quoting and you won't have to use all those backslashes..

Comment: Surely there is an exception if everything is rolled back?

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes, its "not all arguments converted during string formatting"

Comment: Right, that fits my answer exactly then; you are trying to run the `stmt` SQL with `('n', 'a', 'm', 'e', '1')` and `('s', 't', 'a', 't', 'u', 's', '1')` as the parameters, respectively, and since there are no positional bind parameters in `stmt` none of those parameter values are used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`executemany()` takes a *sequence* of parameter objects (dictionaries), but you are passing in just **one**. Either use `dbcursor.execute()`, or pass in a sequence of dictionaries. Since you only have one dictionary, just use `dbcursor.execute()`:

```
dbcursor.execute(stmt, dic)
```

Because `executemany()` treats the second argument as a series of parameters, each of which is used in a separate `execute()` call, you are effectively trying to run the statements with the *keys* of the dictionary as the parameters. In effect, passing in your `dic` as the parameters produces:

```
for key in dic:
    dbcursor.execute(stmt, key)
```

where the key is also an iterable, producing separate *characters* as the parameters used. You are trying to run the statement with `('n', 'a', 'm', 'e', '1')` and `('s', 't', 'a', 't', 'u', 's', '1')`. That doesn't work for your statements.

Comment: Just tried this. The error is telling me to check my syntax, so this is progress and I am checking my sql version now for syntax rules